# Copy and Delete Sound Effects

Tags: 16.04, sound, nautilus

I want to have some loop sound effect when copy and delete progress showing up until the progress done.

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want a custom sound file being looped during any copy or delete action process? Is that correct?

Comment: @OwenHines Yes.  I want loop sound effect until the progress reach to the %100.

Comment: How are you copying and deleting these files? If it's a script can you include the commands in your question?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm using Nautilus.

Comment: I doubt that's possible without changing the source code of Nautilus or using something else to move and copy files.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Got something on my mind. If we have a listener to check if nautilus "file operation" window is open and then play loop sound until "file operation" window gone. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: That would work but it requires polling the window manager state. If you need to poll a state then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: This would be relatively straightforward if using a script.. You could use mplayer and a while loop...

Answer (score 0):

If you copy files from the terminal I have [written a script](https://github.com/samrocketman/home/blob/master/bin/say_job_done.sh) which works for me on Ubuntu and Mac OS X.  Example usage if the script is in your `$PATH`:

```
cp -r /src /dst ; say_job_done.sh
```

It must all be typed on one line so that it will execute when the files are finished being copied.  If you want copy progress you can use a program like [`rsync(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/rsync.1.html).

`say_job_done.sh` requires `espeak` package to be installed in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo apt-get install espeak
```

## Alternatively

Without my script you can call [`espeak(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/espeak.1.html) directly.  Note: below syntax uses a `Here String` in [`bash(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc14).

```
cp -r /src /dst ; espeak <<< "Jobb done."
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need something to work with Nautilus as you can see on my question tags.

Comment: I understand.  I added my answer for those who might be looking for an alternative solution.  If I figure out how to do it in Nautilus I'll update my answer.

Comment: Nautilus scripts looks like a promising solution.  I'll play with it. - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto